# Is there a way to refresh Notepad?

Tags: notepad

Say, for example, that there's one process that's writing to a file. While the process is running, I opened the file in notepad. The process keeps  writing to the file.

Other than closing and reopening the file, is there any way for me to "refresh" the data that notepad is showing?

Comment: Use Notepad2 (F5 refreshes)

Comment: Use a Windows port of the Unix _tail_ command

Comment: Get Notepad++!!!

Comment: Many of the comments assume that the user has OS level privileges to install another program.  In some environments, that is not permitted.  So the short answer is: no, there is no quick and easy way to refresh the loaded file.  Reloading via CTRL-O works, but becomes more mousing/keystrokes if the file does not have ".TXT" extension.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While it isn't possible with notepad, there are many notepad replacements. They usually have this feature. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is my personal favorite, and the one I'd recommend.

Comment: Notepad2, like stated in the comment of the question, is much more like regular notepad, but with all the advantages of Notepad++.

Comment: And I still have to google for it. http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html

Answer (score 21):

No.

Here are some more words to make the answer long enough to go beyond the 30-character minimum.

Answer (score 7):

> Other than closing and reopening the file...

You don't have to close the file.  Use file>Open or <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to reopen the file.  That way you don't have to open a new instance of notepad.

Other than that, I agree with everyone else.  Use a different editor.

Answer (score 4):

No, however if you use other Notepad alternatives like, [Notepad+](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)+ it will notify you if the file has been altered since opened.

Comment: You can even set it to auto-update, if you wish. It's all in the Tools->Settings->Misc section.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to watch a file as it is actively being written to, then you want a program capable of following it such as [baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

Baretail is a great program, but better is the free [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/en/download.php), which I use for all kinds of text file editing, including programming and it has syntax highlighting for a couple dozen different kinds of programming languages/file types, which is really nice.  It also has an autorefresh, and the refresh rate is settable in the settings (I like 3 seconds).